# Old and new values in Oracle Form

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm working with Oracle Forms. I have a field named `SOLD_TO_CUST_PARTY_NAME`. I have to execute a process if I detect a change in the field's value. I tried using when_validate, but it's executed even if you just click the field and move to another field (validation ALWAYS occurs whether you change the value or not). Is there anyway I can check `:old` and `:new` or something similar to execute a process only if the field is modified?

**EDIT:**
Can't use personalizations. It has to be done with `pl/sql`.

Comment: when-validate will fire only if there's a change, not otherwise. Something's clearing your item and repopulating it again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a property called database value that let you check if the field has been modified and if it has not you just have to exit the validation trigger.

Ex.

```
    BEGIN

    IF :BLOCK.ITEM = GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK.ITEM', database_value) THEN
     RETURN;
    END IF;

     /* VALIDATION */

    END;
```

Comment: I guess this construct is used to also handle null values. A simple 
IF :BLOCK.ITEM != GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK.ITEM', database_value) THEN
  /*VALIDATION*/
END IF;

wouldn't handle those.