# How to keep initial value of a field after POST is done

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms app. There is a form with a date field and I need to keep it initial value (when form is loaded), to compare it with actual value in the field. Also there is a button on the form, that posts changes.

I've tried to store initial value with global variable and check if it's changed, also I've tried to simply check that :system.record_status != 'QUERY' to track if date is modified.

Problem that at the moment, when button is pressed and post is done the values of all global variables become null, so I can't compare the initial value with the new one and :system.record_status becomes 'QUERY' again, and I don't see any more if user modified something.

How to keep the initial values or track that data was changed, doesn't matter if user posts changes or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old and new values in Oracle Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606881/old-and-new-values-in-oracle-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> Problem that at the moment, when button is pressed and **post is done the values of all global variables become null**, so I can't compare the initial value with the new one

doesn't work that way. Post (if you refer to `POST` built-in) (nor `COMMIT`, as we're at it) doesn't clear global variables. Explicitly setting it to NULL does, so - check the form whether you've done it somewhere in your code. How? Run the form in debug mode, trace its execution and see what's going on.

Another thing that might be going wrong is that global variables's datatype is `CHAR` so - if you plan to compare it to a different datatype value, you should perform conversion. As it is a date value, consider applying `TO_DATE` function to the global variable with appropriate format mask.

Comment: Actually your answer doesn't have a solution of the problem, but you lead me to the answer. So, I went through the code with debug... Post isn't the reason of the problem. The real code that causes "reset" of global variables and status of record (which is right for the second case), it's a call of EXECUTE_QUERY command. What I did is: save the value of the global variable to a local one then set it back. Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I told you that POST isn't to be blamed. I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know!

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
     IF GET_ITEM_PROPERTY(:SYSTEM.CURSOR_ITEM,UPDATE_COLUMN) ='TRUE' THEN
     Copy(Get_Item_Property(itm, Database_Value), :System.Cursor_Item);
```